# Initiate property inside python class

Tags: python, class, properties

I'm trying to initiate a property inside a class but it doesn't seem to work.
The class should use another class. this is the code I've made:

Book.py:

```
 from Paragraph import Paragraph as Paragraph

'''definitions'''
class Book:
    def __init__(self, book):
        self._paragraphs = book

    '''paragraphs property'''
    @property
    def paragraphs(self):
        return self._paragraphs

    @paragraphs.setter
    def paragraphs(self, book):
        paragraph_0 = Paragraph(book[0x0:0x100])
        paragraph_1 = Paragraph(book[0x200:0x300])
        paragraph_2 = Paragraph(book[0x300:0x400])
        paragraph_3 = Paragraph(book[0x400:0x500])
        self._paragraphs = [paragraph_0, paragraph_1, paragraph_2, paragraph_3]
```

Paragraph.py:

```
    '''definitions'''
    class Paragraph:
        def __init__(self, paragraph):
            self._paragraph = paragraph
            self._first_section = paragraph[0x0:0x10]
            self._second_section = paragraph[0x10:0x100]

        '''paragraph property'''
        @property
        def paragraph(self):
            return self._paragraph

        @paragraph.setter
        def paragraph(self, paragraph):
            self._paragraph = paragraph

        '''first_section property'''
        @property
        def first_section(self):
            return self._first_section

        @first_section.setter
        def first_section(self, first_section):
            self._first_section = first_section

        '''second_section property'''
        @property
        def second_section(self):
            return self._second_section

        @second_section.setter
        def second_section(self, second_section):
            self._second_section = second_section
```

Then I create a Book instance:

```
first_book = Book(some_hex_list)
```

And I expect to have 4 paragraphs in `first_book._paragraphs` and each paragraph should have a first and a second section property (as in the Paragraph class). Instead `first_book._paragraphs` just contains the original `some_hex_list` data.

I'd like to create a Book instance and initiate it so in the end I should get something like this:

```
first_book
-->_paragraphs
----->paragraph_0
---------->_first_section
---------->_second_section
----->paragraph_1
---------->_first_section
---------->_second_section
----->paragraph_2
---------->_first_section
---------->_second_section
----->paragraph_3
---------->_first_section
---------->_second_section
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're not using the setter - you're doing `self._paragraphs = book` in init, which directly changes `_paragraphs`

Comment: OK, how to use the setter properly?

Comment: I know naming things is [difficult](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html) but `from Paragraph import Paragraph as Paragraph` just looks wrong ...

Comment: @IonutTicus at the very least, `import Paragraph as Paragraph` is just nonsense, since the alias is exactly the same.